# Creating an issue in Jira from python error - Epic Link Field is Empty

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I am trying the very basics of creating a task in jira through python using the module `jira==3.5.2`: https://jira.readthedocs.io/

I have the following code in my `constants.py` file:

```
from jira import JIRA

JIRA_TOKEN = "TOKEN"

ji = JIRA('https://ourdomain.atlassian.net', basic_auth=('myname@companyname.com', JIRA_TOKEN))
```

And the following code in `main.py`:

```
from constants import *
from pprint import pprint

def jira_create_issue(summary: str, description: str):

    issue_dict = {
        'project': {'key': 'QD'},
        'summary': 'TEST JIRA PYTHON',
        'description': 'test',
        'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
    }

    new_issue = ji.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)

def main():
    jira_create_issue("test rest", "test rest1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Whenever creating an issue like this, I get an `HTTP 400` error saying:

`response text = {"errorMessages":["Epic Link Field is Empty !"],"errors":{}}`

When I try to include the epic link field in `issue_dict` (I've tried many forms: `epiclink, EpicLink, Epic Link, epic link, epic` and so on...), I get the following error:

`response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"Epic Link":"Field 'Epic Link' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}`

What am I doing wrong? When opening a task in out Jira dashboard manually, I do have an Epic Link field with a drop down to set.
But what is the name of the key of it? It isn't written anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `Epic Link` is a custom field added by my company, therefore it's "display name" is different from it's actual key.

I found out that it's key was `customfield_10002` by using the method `JIRA.fields()` which returns a list of all issue fields. I then just searched using `ctrl + F` for `Epic Link`, and looked at it's `key`.

My final `issue_dict` looks like so:

```
issue_dict = {
        'project': {'key': 'QD'},
        'summary': 'TEST JIRA PYTHON',
        'description': 'test',
        'issuetype': {'name': 'Bug'},
        EPIC_LINK_FIELD: "QD-9913"
    }
```

where `EPIC_LINK_FIELD` is said key and `QD-9913` is the key of the epic link I need (can be found under the name of each epic link in the epic link dropdown).